# MacOS sometimes didn't boot after login when eGPU is connected

Tags: macos, catalina, login, gpu

Issue is simple:
When I launching MacBook Pro and login, after this loading bar is not appear and os stuck on that view.
It happening sometimes when eGPU is connected.
eGPU: Razer Core X + AMD Radeon 5700 XT Gaming X